# Linux- OPENSUSE ipv6 related configurations in sysctl.conf lost after reboot

Tags: ipv6, opensuse

I am using:
    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
    VERSION = 11
    PATCHLEVEL = 1

I added the following parameters to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
```

Ran:

```
sysctl -p
```

And checked the vaules by:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects
0
```

When I rebooted the machine, `'0'` was changed back to `'1'` in `/proc` filesystem:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects
1
```

`sysctl.conf` still has:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
```

I have checked following links:

```
Bug 807257 - SuSeFirewall reverts to default sysctl network related settings
http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2011/09/04/linux-ipv6-router-advertisements-and-forwarding/
http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=123617372002934&w=2
http://serverfault.com/questions/270201/sysctl-conf-not-running-on-boot
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167678
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/50093
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=654585
http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2527
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=539869
```

Unfortunately, these links do not help because the files such as `/etc/sysctl.d` and `/etc/init.d/procps`  to which these links refer to are not present in my machine.

I would like to know what is causing the `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects` to revert back to `'1'`.

thank you.

Comment: Do other settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` work? Your question makes it sound like all the settings in there work except the IPv6 settings. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is only the IPv6 settings which do not persist in /proc file-system after a reboot. Other settings, i.e. those related to ipv4 persist after reboot also. Today, I added "ipv6" entry in /etc/sysconfig/kernel and ran mkinitrd after that. This seems to work. I am now trying to find a solution that works without rebuilding the init RAM

Comment: http://forum.proxmox.com/archive/index.php/t-14103.html says that on a ProxMos system, adding "up sysctl -p" in  /etc/network/interfaces works. I am looking for a file in openSuse which can be configured with similar setting. (since /etc/network/interfaces is not there)

Answer (score 0):

I see this as well on SLES11 SP1; not on SP3.

It seems like there may be a race condition between when the ipv6 kernel module is loaded and when /etc/sysctl.conf is processed during boot (/etc/init.d/boot.sysctl).  The ipv6 module may not otherwise load until the /etc/init.d/boot.ipconfig script runs (after boot.sysctl).  Interestingly the ordering of these scripts is the same in SP1 and SP3, even though things work on SP3.

If you insert a 'modprobe ipv6' in this boot.sysctl then the ipv6 settings will persist as expected:

```
        echo -n "Setting current sysctl status from /etc/sysctl.conf"
        # Force ipv6 module to load
        modprobe ipv6
        sysctl -e -q -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```